# Add comma before last two numbers and keep dots after three numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input that has a formatter to add a dot after every three numbers, but I need to make it a flot with a comma before the last two numbers. Right now, my code is like this, but I don't know how to put the comma before the last two digits.

```
<InputNumber
    formatter={value => String(value).replace(/\D/g, '').split(/(?=(?:\d{3})*$)/g).join('.')}
    max={1000000}
    parser={value => String(value).replace(/\D/g, '')}
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
/>
```

The output is 2.000 for example, but I need it to be 2.000,00

Answer (score 2):

you can use Intl.NumberFormat API of browser.
the Format you want that is use for Italy and some other europian country.

e.g. `new Intl.NumberFormat('IT', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}).format('100000')`

```
<InputNumber
    formatter={value => new Intl.NumberFormat('IT', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}).format(value)}
    max={1000000}
    parser={value => String(value).replace(/\D/g, '')}
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
/>
```

Comment: This is not working. Everytime I digit a number, it adds three more zeros